Maximizing the expected deviation of sum of independent Bernoulli
Let $(X_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables such that $X_i \sim \mathcal{B}(p_i)$ where $p_i\in\left\{\alpha_i, 1-\alpha_i\right\}$.
Show that the values of $(p_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ maximizing $E\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \frac{n}{2}\right|\right]$ are
$$
(p_i)_{1\leq i \leq n} = (\alpha_i\wedge (1-\alpha_i))_{1\leq i \leq n}\quad \text{ and } \quad(p_i)_{1\leq i \leq n} = (\alpha_i\vee (1-\alpha_i))_{1\leq i \leq n}.
$$
I can prove the result when all $\alpha_i$ are equal, but not in the general case...
Motivation
I was studying the problem of clustering, and I wanted to identify the minimizer of the risk of clustering in expectation and the situations where it coincides with the celebrated Bayes classifier in the case of only two clusters. This reduces to the problem above after many simplifications. For those interested, you can take a look at the second section of this paper for some context.

What do $\alpha_i\wedge (1-\alpha_i)$ and $\alpha_i\vee (1-\alpha_i)$ mean if $\alpha_i$ is a real number? Minimum and maximum (or the other way round)?

Yes, the max and min :).

The $\alpha_i$ are bounded between 0 and 1 of course.

I only worked out the $n\leq3$ case, where the expectation is $\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i)+\prod_{i=1}^np_i+\frac{n}{2}-1$ and the result can be verified. This expectation doesn't work for $n\geq4$.

Yes the formula of the expectation is much more involved in the general case.

By the way, when replacing the expectation of the absolute value by that of the second moment, the result is somewhat easier to prove: It suffices to study the gradient and things become smooth. However, the gradient of the expectation of the absolute deviation is just awful to analyze.

@Ibra Can you please provide some detail? I also tried the 2nd moment, but I got an indefinite Hessian and stuck there...

@ZackFisher, WLOG, assume $\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j \geq \frac{n}{2}$. For every $j\in[n]$ such that $p_j < \frac{1}{2}$, I compute the partial derivative of $E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \frac{n}{2}\right)^2\right]$ with respect to $p_j$ and it is easy to show that it is positive. In other words, swapping this $p_j$ to $1-p_j$ increases the value of the expectation. This means, for every choice of the prameters such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_j \geq \frac{n}{2}$ I can always show that the expectation is smaller than that with parameters $(p_i) = (\alpha_i\vee (1-\alpha_i))$. The result follows.

@ZackFisher I think in the case of the second moment, there is no need to study the Hessian. Analyzing the sign of the partial derivatives at these specific indices is enough as detailed in the previous comment. By symmetry, the assumption $\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j \geq n/2$ is not a loss of generality.

A slightly simpler and more general (conjecture): if $Z =  \sum_i a_i Z_i $, where $Z_i$ are independent r.v. with $E[Z_i] >0$, and $a_i \in {1,-1}$ , then $E|Z|$ is maximized when $a_i = 1 $ $\forall i$, or $a_i = -1 $ $\forall i$

@leonbloy Thank you for your remark. The conjecture seems to be interesting  and more general.

The expectation (except for the $n=1$ trivial case) is $$\sum_{k=m+1}^{2m}(-1)^{m+k+1}\binom{k-2}{m-1}\left(2-s_n\cdot \frac{k-1}m\right) P(k)-\sum_{i=1}^n p_i +\frac{n}2,$$
where $s_n={n}\mod{2}$, $m=\left\lfloor \frac{n}2 \right\rfloor$, and
$
P(k)=\sum_{q\in Q([n],k)} \prod_{i\in q} p_i
$
with $Q(\mathcal{A},k)=\left\lbrace q\subseteq\mathcal{A}:|q|=k\right\rbrace$ and $[n]=\lbrace 1,2,\dots,n\rbrace$.
As the OP commented above, this expectation is probably not easy to analyze.

@Ibra Out of curiosity, what's the context of this question? Is it an exercise from a book? (Given how intuitive the result is, it's surprisingly difficult!)

@leonbloy I'm suspicious that such a general result holds—I sketched a possible way to get a counterexample in my answer

@Ziv Thanks, I'll look at it. You might want to answer or link here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4962549/a-conjectured-inequality-about-the-expected-absolute-value-of-a-signed-sum-of-ra

@Ziv, I was studying the problem of clustering, and I wanted to identify the minimizer of the risk of clustering in expectation and the situations where it coincides with the celebrated Bayes classifier in the case of only two clusters. This reduces to the problem above after many simplifications. For those interested, you can take a look at the second section of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.12238 for some context.

WLOG let $\alpha_i \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $i$. Let's call setting $p_i = \alpha_i$ giving $i$ positive bias, and similarly call $p_i = 1 - \alpha_i$ negative bias.
Our approach is to use an interchange argument. Specifically, we show that unless we give all positive bias or all negative bias, then we can flip the bias of some $i$ to increase the expectation of the absolute deviation.
Contents

Reframe the problem
Analyze the impact of one term's bias
Show same-sign bias is optimal under an extra assumption
Remove the assumption
Generalize?

1. Reframe the problem
To make this easier to notate, we introduce the bias into our notation. Let $Z_i \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\alpha_i)$ be an independent sequence, and let $\beta_i \in \{-1, +1\}$ be the bias we give $i$. We then let
$$\begin{aligned}
    Y_i &= 2 Z_i - 1 \in \{-1, +1\}, \\
    X_i &= \frac{1 + \beta_i Y_i}{2} \in \{0, 1\}.
\end{aligned}$$
You can check that $X_i$ has the desired distribution... but we're actually going to work entirely in terms of $Y_i$. Specifically, you can check that
$$
    \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i - \frac{n}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^n \beta_i Y_i.
$$
So, letting $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \beta_i Y_i$, our goal is to choose the $\beta_i$ to maximize $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$.
2. Analyze the impact of one bias
We want to understand the effect $\beta_i$ has on $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$. Without loss of generality, let's look at the case $i = n$. Specifically, we're going to rewrite $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$ as a sum of $\mathbb{E}[|S_{n - 1}|]$ and terms that make clear what the impact of $\beta_i$ is.
To facilitate this, let's rewrite $|S_n|$ as $S \operatorname{sign}(S_n)$, where
$$
    \operatorname{sign}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x > 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0 \\ -1 & \text{if } x < 0. \end{cases}
$$
From this, we compute
$$\begin{aligned}
    |S_n|
    &= S_n \operatorname{sign}(S_n) \\
    &= S_n \operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1}) + S_n \bigl(\operatorname{sign}(S_n) - \operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1})\bigr) \\
    &= S_{n - 1} \operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1}) + \beta_n Y_n \operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1}) + S_n \bigl(\operatorname{sign}(S_n) - \operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1})\bigr) \\
    &= |S_{n - 1}| + \beta_n Y_n \operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1}) + \mathbf{1}(S_{n - 1} = 0).
\end{aligned}$$
(Above, the third term in the last line follows from doing casework on $S_n \bigl(\operatorname{sign}(S_n) - \operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1})\bigr)$. In short, if the first factor $S_n \neq 0$, the second factor is nonzero only if $S_{n - 1} = 0$ , in which case $S_n \in \{-1, +1\}$.)
By the computation above and the fact that $S_{n - 1}$ and $Y_n$ are independent,
$$
    \mathbb{E}[|S_n|] = \mathbb{E}[|S_{n - 1}|] + \mathbb{P}[S_{n - 1} = 0] + \beta_n \, \mathbb{E}[Y_n] \, \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1})].
$$
Because $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] \geq 0$, we conclude that if we fix the values of $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_{n - 1}$, then the value of $\beta_n$ that maximizes $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$ is
$$
    \beta_n = \operatorname{sign}\bigl(\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1})]\bigr).
$$
(Or, if the right-hand side is $0$, then either choice $\beta_n \in \{-1, +1\}$ is the same. This will show up again below, and I won't keep pointing it out. If you like, you can allow $\beta_i \in \{-1, 0, +1\}$, as it turns out that there is always an optimal choice that does not include $0$.)
3. Show same-sign bias is optimal under an extra assumption
Let's start by rewriting what we learned above in a way that applies to any index $k$, not just $k = n$: if the values of $\beta_i$ are fixed for all $i \neq k$, then the optimal value for $\beta_k$ is
$$
    \beta_k = \operatorname{sign}\biggl( \mathbb{E}\Bigl[ \operatorname{sign}\Bigl( \sum_{i \neq k} \beta_i Y_i \Bigr) \Bigl] \biggr).
$$
Letting $S_{\neq k} = \sum_{i \neq k} \beta_i Y_i$, we can rewrite this as
$$
    \beta_k = \operatorname{sign}\bigl( \mathbb{E}[ \operatorname{sign}(S_{\neq k}) ] \bigr).
$$
This is roughly analogous to a first-order optimality condition. That is, the optimal values of $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$ must obey the above condition for all $k$.
For now, we make an assumption to simplify the argument.

Assumption 1. All the $\alpha_i$ are distinct and obey $\alpha_i > \frac{1}{2}$.

This assumption will guarantee that for non-same-sign biases, there is always at least one bias we can flip to strictly increase $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$. We will remove this assumption in the next section. (It may be possible to prove the result without going via a version with this assumption, but it might require thinking about flipping multiple biases at once.)
With Assumption 1 in hand, I leave showing the following fact as exercises (e.g. use coupling arguments). Consider any assignment of the biases $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$.

Fact 1. The values $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\neq j})]$ are distinct for distinct $j$, so there exists $k$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\neq k})] \neq 0$.

Roughly, Fact 1 holds because each term has a different impact on the probability of the sum being positive or negative, because the $\alpha_i$ are distinct. (We are also implicitly assuming here that $n \geq 2$, but this is fine because the $n = 1$ case is trivial.)
We will also need the following fact, which I prove at the end of this section.

Fact 2. Suppose $\beta_j = 1$ and $\beta_k = -1$. Then $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\neq k})] \geq \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\neq j})]$.

Roughly, Fact 2 holds because swapping a positive-bias term $+Y_j$ out for a negative-bias term $-Y_k$ makes the sum less likely to be positive.
With these facts in hand, consider any non-same-sign biases $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$. By Fact 1, there exists $k$ such that
$$
    \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\neq k})] \neq 0.
$$
WLOG, suppose $\beta_k = -1$. There are two cases to consider.

If $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\neq k})] > 0$, then $\beta_k$ disobeys the first-order optimality condition, so swapping to $\beta_k = 1$ increases $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$.
If $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\neq k})] < 0$, then $\beta_k$ obeys the first-order optimality condition, so we need to find another bias to swap. Because the assignment is non-same-sign, there exists $j$ such that $\beta_j = 1$. And by Fact 2, $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\neq j})] < 0$. This means $\beta_j$ disobeys the first-order optimality condition, so swapping to $\beta_j = -1$ increases $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$.

We have shown that any non-same-sign bias assignment is suboptimal for maximizing $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$, so only the same-sign cases can be optimal. And it is clear by symmetry that they both yield the same $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$ value, so both are optimal.
Proof of Fact 2
Let $S_{\not\in \{j, k\}} = \sum_{i \not\in \{j, k\}} \beta_i Y_i$. We want to show that
$$
    \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\not\in \{j, k\}} + Y_j)]
    \geq \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\not\in \{j, k\}} - Y_k)].
$$
The key observation is that we have a stochastic dominance $+Y_j \geq_{\mathrm{st}} -Y_k$. This means that for any weakly increasing (i.e. nondecreasing) function $f$,
$$
    \mathbb{E}[f(+Y_j)]
    \geq \mathbb{E}[f(-Y_k)].
$$
The desired result follows by applying the above to
$$
    f(x) = \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{sign}(S_{\not\in \{j, k\}} + x)],
$$
which is clearly nondecreasing. (Note that the validity of considering this function $f$ implicitly uses the independence of $S_{\not\in \{j, k\}}$ from $Y_j$ and $Y_k$.)
One can strengthen the $\geq$ in Fact 2 to a $>$, but this requires some extra effort, and it is not necessary for this answer.
4. Remove the assumption
We have actually just shown that under Assumption 1, same-sign bias gives the unique way to maximize $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$. When Assumption 1 does not hold, it may be the case that there are other maximizers. But the argument below shows that same-sign bias is still a maximizer, even if it's not unique.
The basic idea is to think about $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$ as a function of the probabilities $\alpha_i \in \bigl[\frac{1}{2}, 1\bigr]$ and the biases $\beta_i \in \{-1, +1\}$. To make these dependencies explicit, let us write
$$
    f(\alpha, \beta) = \mathbb{E}[|S_n|],
$$
where $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$ and $\beta = (\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n)$ are vectors.
With this notation in hand, we can write what we've shown already as follows: for all $\alpha \in \bigl[\frac{1}{2}, 1\bigr]^n$ that satisfy Assumption 1 and all $\beta \in \{-1, +1\}^n$,
$$
    f(\alpha, \beta) \leq f(\alpha, \pm u),
$$
where $u = (1, \dots, 1)$. The key observation that extends this to all $\alpha \in \bigl[\frac{1}{2}, 1\bigr]^n$ is the following fact, which I also leave as an exercise (e.g. express $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$ as a polynomial in the $\alpha_i$.).

Fact 3 For all fixed $\beta$, the function $\alpha \mapsto f(\alpha, \beta)$ is continuous.

Given any $\alpha$ that doesn't satisfy Assumption 1, there exists a sequence $\alpha^{(1)}, \alpha^{(2)}, \dots$ that converges to $\alpha$ such that all $\alpha^{(\ell)}$ satisfy Assumption 1. (For instance, pick some small $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $\alpha^{(\ell)}_i = \alpha_i + \frac{\varepsilon i}{\ell}$.) Fact 3 then implies that for all $\beta$,
$$\begin{aligned}
    f(\alpha, \beta)
    &= \lim_{\ell \to \infty} f(\alpha^{(\ell)}, \beta) \\
    &\leq \lim_{\ell \to \infty} f(\alpha^{(\ell)}, \pm u) \\
    &= f(\alpha, \pm u).
\end{aligned}$$
So same-sign bias $\beta = \pm u$ maximizes $f(\alpha, \beta) = \mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$ regardless of whether $\alpha$ satisfies Assumption 1.
5. Generalize?
@leonbloy conjectures in a comment that a similar result should hold for any independent variables $Y_i$ such that $\mathbb{E}[Y_i] > 0$ for all $i$. The main term that needs to be analyzed differently in this more general case is $S_n \bigl(\operatorname{sign}(S_n) - \operatorname{sign}(S_{n - 1})\bigr)$.
I am skeptical that the conjecture holds. Here is an idea that I think will yield a counterexample. Imagine a case where $\mathbb{E}[Y_i] = 0$ for all $i$, but the $Y_i$ are asymmetrical. Then it seems unlikely that $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$ is the same for all ways of setting $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$. By flipping the signs of the $Y_i$, we can probably make it so that all ways of setting $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$ that maximize $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]$ are not same-sign. But then adding some $\epsilon > 0$ to all the $Y_i$ should give a counterexample.
The counterexample sketch above is ruled out if we restrict to $Y_i \in \{-1, +1\}$, as is the case in the original question, because then the only way to get $\mathbb{E}[Y_i] = 0$ is to make $Y_i$ symmetrical.

I have added a what I think is short proof of Fact 2. Or is there a subtlety I'm missing?

Thank you very much for this clearly written answer. I believe it is correct.

WLOG, assume $\frac{1}{2} < \alpha_i < 1$ (I believe it would be similar or easier to deal with $\alpha_i = 1 - \alpha_i = \frac{1}{2}$ or $\alpha_i \in \{0, 1\}$).
We have $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \frac{n}{2}\right|\right] = \sum_{y = 0}^{n} \Pr[\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = y] \left|y - \frac{n}{2}\right|.$$
Let $T := \{i \in [n] \colon p_i = \alpha_i \}$, we have
$$Y_T := \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = \sum_{i \in T} Ber(\alpha_i) + \sum_{i \not \in T} Ber(1 - \alpha_i).$$
Claim 1: If $T \notin \{\emptyset, [n]\}$, you can get higher $\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \frac{n}{2}\right|\right]$ by flipping one $p_i$ with either (1) $\alpha_i \to 1 - \alpha_i$ or (2) vice versa, i.e., $1 - \alpha_i \to \alpha_i$. This implies that the maximum must be achieved at an extreme.
Note 1: I mean for non-extreme cases, we can either (1) flip one $\alpha_i$ to $1 - \alpha_i$ for some $i$ or (2) flip one $1 - \alpha_j$ to $\alpha_j$ for some $j$ to increase the expectation, so any non-extreme case cannot be maximum. I am not claiming it's always the case (1) or always the case (2), but one between (1) and (2) should be true.
To show so, we analyze the change in $Y_T$ when we flip one $p_i$.
Below, we show when we flip one $p_i$ from $1 - \alpha_i$ to $\alpha_i$, and the analysis of the opposite direction would be similar.
Pick some $j \notin T$ and make $R := T \cup \{j\}$,
let
$$Y_R:= \sum_{i \in R} Ber(\alpha_i) + \sum_{i \notin R} Ber(1 - \alpha_i),$$
we can think
$$Y_T = \sum_{i \in T} Ber(\alpha_i) + \sum_{i \notin R} Ber(1 - \alpha_i) + Ber(1 - \alpha_j)$$ and
$$Y_R = \sum_{i \in T} Ber(\alpha_i) + \sum_{i \notin R} Ber(1 - \alpha_i) + Ber(\alpha_j).$$
Now, let
$$Y_0 := \sum_{i \in T} Ber(\alpha_i) + \sum_{i \notin R} Ber(1 - \alpha_i),$$
we have
\begin{align*}
\Pr[Y_T = 0] &= \Pr[Y_0 = 0] \alpha_j, \\
\Pr[Y_T = y] &= \Pr[Y_0 = y] \alpha_j + \Pr[Y_0 = y - 1] (1- \alpha_j), \forall 1 \leq y \leq n - 1, \\
\Pr[Y_T = n] &= \Pr[Y_0 = n - 1] (1- \alpha_j)\\
\Pr[Y_R = 0] &= \Pr[Y_0 = 0] (1 - \alpha_j),~\text{and} \\
\Pr[Y_R = y] &= \Pr[Y_0 = y] (1 - \alpha_j) + \Pr[Y_0 = y-1] \alpha_j, \forall 1 \leq y \leq n - 1, \\
\Pr[Y_R = n] &= \Pr[Y_0 = n - 1] \alpha_j.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we have
$$\Pr[Y_0 = 0] = \frac{\Pr[Y_T = 0]}{\alpha_j}$$ and
$$\Pr[Y_0 = y] = \frac{\sum_{k = 0}^{y} \Pr[Y_T = y - k] \left(\frac{\alpha_j - 1}{\alpha_j}\right)^{k}}{\alpha_j}, \forall 1 \leq y \geq n - 1,$$
which in turn gives
$$\Pr[Y_R = 0] = \Pr[Y_T = 0] \frac{1 - \alpha_j}{\alpha_j},$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr[Y_R = 1] &= \Pr[Y_T = 0] \frac{2\alpha_j - 1}{\alpha^2_j} + \Pr[Y_T = 1] \frac{1 - \alpha_j}{\alpha_j},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\Pr[Y_R = y] &= \Pr[Y_0 = y] + \Pr[Y_0 = y - 1] - \Pr[Y_T = y] \\
&= \frac{\Pr[Y_T = y] (1 - \alpha_j) + \sum_{k=0}^{y - 1} \Pr[Y_T = y - 1 - k] \left(\frac{\alpha_j - 1}{\alpha_j}\right)^{k} \frac{2 \alpha_j - 1}{\alpha_j}}{\alpha_j}, \forall 1 \leq y \leq n - 1.
\end{align*}
Similarly, from the other direction (i.e., from $y = n$ to $y = 0$), we have
$$\Pr[Y_0 = n - 1] = \frac{\Pr[Y_T = n]}{1 - \alpha_j}$$
and
$$\Pr[Y_0 = n - z] = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^z \Pr[Y_T = n - z + k] \left( 
\frac{\alpha_j}{\alpha_j - 1} \right)^{k-1}}{1 - \alpha_j}, \forall 1 \leq z \leq n - 1,$$
which in turn gives
$$\Pr[Y_R = n] = \Pr[Y_T = n] \frac{\alpha_j}{1 - \alpha_j},$$
$$\Pr[Y_R = n - 1] = \frac{1 - 2 \alpha_j}{(1 - \alpha_j)^2} \Pr[Y_T = n] + \frac{\alpha_j}{1 - \alpha_j} \Pr[Y_T = n - 1],$$
and
$$\Pr[Y_R = y] = \Pr[Y_T = y] \frac{\alpha_j}{1 - \alpha_j} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n - y} \left(\frac{\alpha_j }{\alpha_j - 1}\right)^{k - 1} \frac{1 - 2\alpha_j}{\left( 1 - \alpha_j \right)^2}, \forall 1 \leq y \leq n - 2.$$
Claim 2: If $\prod_{i = 1}^n {p_i} > \prod_{i = 1}^n {1 - p_i}$, there exists some threshold $y_0 \in [0, \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor]$ such that $\Pr[Y_R = n - y] + \Pr[Y_R = y] > \Pr[Y_T = n - y] + \Pr[Y_T = y]$ iff $y \leq y_0$.
Since
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \frac{n}{2}\right|\right] &= \sum_{y = 0}^{n} \Pr[\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = y] \left|y - \frac{n}{2}\right| \\
&= \sum_{y = 0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \left( \Pr[\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = y] + \Pr[\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = n - y] \right) \left( \frac{n}{2} - y \right),
\end{align*}
this implies that
$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \frac{n}{2}\right|\right]$ increases (the weights shift to higher values).
(1) First,
$$\Pr[Y_R = n] + \Pr[Y_R = 0] > \Pr[Y_T = n] + \Pr[Y_T = 0] \Leftrightarrow \Pr[Y_T = n] \alpha_j > \Pr[Y_T = 0] (1 - \alpha_j) \Leftarrow \Pr[Y_T = n] > \Pr[Y_T = 0] \Leftrightarrow \prod_{i = 1}^n {p_i} > \prod_{i = 1}^n {1 - p_i}.$$
(2) Then,
$$\Pr[Y_R = n - 1] + \Pr[Y_R = 1] > \Pr[Y_T = n - 1] + \Pr[Y_T = 1] \Leftrightarrow 
\frac{\Pr[Y_T = 0]}{\alpha^2_j} -
\frac{\Pr[Y_T = 1]}{\alpha_j} >
\frac{\Pr[Y_T = n]}{(1 - \alpha_j)^2} -
\frac{\Pr[Y_T = n - 1]}{1 - \alpha_j}.$$
(3) One can go on and show that as $y$ increases, the condition for $\Pr[Y_R = n - y] + \Pr[Y_R = y] > \Pr[Y_T = n - y] + \Pr[Y_T = y]$ goes stronger and harder to be satisfied ($\color{red}{\text{more calculation is needed to verify this}}$), and thus it holds for small $y$ and does not hold for large $y$, which is our "Claim 2".

How does the relationship between $\Pr[Y_R=y]$ and $\Pr[Y_T=y]$ relate back to the expectation, please?

I believe your claim is false. It seems to me that the expectation can be increased by flipping $p_i  = 1 - \alpha_i$ to $p_i = \alpha_i$ only in the situation where $\sum_{i\in T} p_i  > n/2$. This should not be true in the general case. Also, I can't conclude the result from your computations.

@Ibra I mean for non-extreme cases, we can either (1) flip one $\alpha_i$ to $1 - \alpha_i$ for some $i$ or (2) flip one $1 - \alpha_j$ to $\alpha_j$ for some $j$ to increase the expectation, so non-extreme case cannot be maximum. I am not claiming it's always case (1), but one between (1) and (2) should be true.

@zack I believe that one between case (1) and (2) (see my response to Ibra) will shift the expectation to a larger value (specifically, $\Pr[Y_R = y] + \Pr[Y_R = n - y]$ increases for large $y$ and decreases for small $y$.

Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm still unable to follow the last step of the reasoning. If more explanation is given, it'll be very appreciated.

@ZackFisher I added more details. Hope it is clearer now.

But honestly some more calculations are still needed at the end to support Claim 2.

Basically, you want to maximize the distance between $\sum_i X_i$ and the fixed value $\frac{n}{2}$ (on average). Given that the random variable $\sum_i X_i$ takes values between $0$ and $n$ and the quantity $\frac{n}{2}$ lies exactly in the middle of this range, two strategies are possible. Either the latter value can be outnumbered by drawing 1's mostly, so that we want high values of $p_i$, hence $p_i = \max(\alpha_i,1-\alpha_i) \;\forall i$. Or, on the contrary, we can remain the furthest away below $\frac{n}{2}$ too, so that we hope to draw 0's mostly, hence low values of $p_i$ and $p_i = \min(\alpha_i,1-\alpha_i) \;\forall i$.

Yes, this intuition is straightforward. The question is how to formalize it mathematically :)
