A conjectured inequality about the expected absolute value of a signed sum of random variables
Musing about another question, I got this conjecture:
General version:
Let $X_i$ be independent (not identical) random variables with $E[X_i] > 0$.
Let $a_i \in \{ 1, -1\}$. Then
$$E \left[\left| \sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i \right|\right] \le E \left[\left| \sum_{i=1}^n  X_i \right|\right]$$
and equality implies: either $a_i=1$ $\forall i$, or $a_i=-1$ $\forall i$.
A more restricted version: Let $P(X_i=1)= p_i$, $P(X_i= -1)= 1-p_i$ with $p_i > \frac12$.
It looks true (at least the restricted version), but I don't know how to tackle it.

The general version is false.
Take two rvs taking only two possible values each:
$$
P(X_1 = -1) = \frac{2}{3}\\
P(X_1 = 3) = \frac{1}{3} \\
P(X_2 = -3) = \frac{2}{3} \\
P(X_2 = 10) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
Now $E(X_1) = -\frac{2}{3} + 1 = \frac{1}{3}$, $E(X_2) = -2 + \frac{10}{3} = \frac{4}{3}$ but
$$
E(|X_1 + X_2|) = \frac{4}{9}\times 4 + \frac{2}{9} \times (9 + 0) + \frac{1}{9} \times 13 = \frac{16 + 18 + 13}{9} = \frac{47}{9}
$$
and
$$
E(|X_1 - X_2|) = \frac{4}{9}\times 2 + \frac{2}{9} \times (11 + 6) + \frac{1}{9} \times 7 = \frac{8 + 34 + 7}{9} = \frac{49}{9}
$$
